# How to scroll down with python selenium without known body height?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I'm trying to scroll down a little bit page with selenium script on react project.

I have tried:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, 1000);")
```

and:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
```

and nothing happens.
In the html code there isnt known 
to the body and I'm getting page boundries by calculate the longest div.
there is a possible way to do scroll in this conditions?
or the problem is that there isnt height to the body?

**its react page so the body propery is 0**

thanks

Comment: Hi did you solved your issue with scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

This will scroll to the bottom of the page.